# Flutter StatefulWidget widgets and generics

Tags: flutter

How can I pass generic type to the `State` of a `StatefulWidget`, Here I want to use my generics in `myMethod<T>`

```dart
class MyWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
  
  myMethod<T>(){
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You just provide the type in your state full widget and then pass it way down to its state:

```
class MyWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState<T> createState() => _MyWidgetState<T>();
}

class _MyWidgetState<T> extends State<MyWidget<T>> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
  
  myMethod<T>() {
    
  }
}
```

Usage:
`MyWidget<String>()`

Answer (score 9):

`_MyWidgetState` need to extends `State<MyWidget<T>>` not just `State<MyWidget>` and then you can use `T` within `_MyWidgetState`

Comment: `Expected to find '>'.`

Comment: you just saved my day, sir

Answer (score 2):

Here's how the Flutter team solves this issue inside the [FutureBuilder](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3595343e20/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart#L686) widget. Instead of having a return type of `_MyWidgetState<T>` for the `createState()`, you would need `State<MyWidget<T>>`.

```dart
State<MyWidget<T>> createState() => _MyWidgetState<T>();
```